# How to sum every 3rd column, based on criteria in every 1st column

Tags: excel-formula

[image]

I am trying to sum R9 and every 3rd column after that, but based on criteria being met in P9 and every 3rd column after that.
However, I manage to create a formula but that is for the amount (you can see the formula below) but what i am trying to get is the QTY. SOLD.
Appreciate if someone can solve this.

Thank you

EDIT:

The formula in text format:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MOD(COLUMN(P9:FI9)-2,3)=0)*(O9:FH9>S3)*(O9:FH9<=S4),(P9:FI9))
```

Comment: Check if the row number is divisible by 3. Then if true multiply.

Comment: Hello Sir could you help me further by providing an accurate formula.? This will really help me alot thank you in advance.

Comment: Please read: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question), and provide formulas as TEXT, and not (only) in a picture   (Because pictures are ..... ., and photos are )

Answer (score 1):

Try the following formula...

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(MOD(COLUMN(R9:AA9)-COLUMN(R9),3)=0),--(P9:Y9>=S3),--(P9:Y9<=S4),R9:AA9)
```

Answer (score 0):

So you can work with this:

[image]

I started at row 3 but you can start at row 9.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you want to sum the 'Qty. Sold' based on the date range given in Cell S3 and S4.

If that's what you want to achieve, you could enter the following formula in Cell FR9 (as in your screenshot), assuming your source data follows the same structure from P9 to FI9.

```
=LET(dates,FILTER($P$9:$FI$9,LEFT($P$8:$FI$8,4)="Tran"),values,FILTER($P$9:$FI$9,$P$8:$FI$8=FS$8),SUM((dates>=$S$3)*(dates<=$S$4)*values))
```

I used the LET formula to define two ranges: 'dates' and 'values'. Within the LET formula, I used the FILTER function to find the 'dates' range by looking at the first four letters of the column header, and used the FILTER function to find the 'values' based on the name of the column, in this case, is 'Qty. Sold'.

Once the 'dates' and 'values' are defined, I used the SUM function to sum all the values that fall within the given date range. Trust this is self-explanatory.

[image: solution]

As shown in the above screenshot, you can drag the formula from cell FS9 to FR9 to obtain the Amount.

Comment: This is amazing. It works accurately. Thankyou so much